# how to open CMD using iis application windows 10 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

how I can open CMD using my IIS Application

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory ="c:\\pdftohtml\\";
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";       
startInfo.Arguments = "MyText";
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I believe this code is true but dose not work with IIS for some reason

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Opening a command prompt from an IIS application is not a good idea.
If you need to run a tool, maybe it's better to find the API used by the tool and reference it from a service called by the IIS app.
If you need to convert pdf to html, check this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Convert-PDF-file-to-HTML-abb731a5)

Comment: I need to Open Patch file using IIS Website,, I need to found solution to this problem,, it's task I need to solve it!

Comment: File.ReadAllText?

Comment: Explain Please!

Comment: var fileContents = File.ReadAllText("file.patch");